# "Unverified Breakpoints" when using VS debugger on Vue components within TS file

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, jupyter, jupyter-lab

**Problem:**
I'm getting unverified breakpoints when I set them in my TS files and Vue components while running VS debugger. I don't know if it's relevant but this is the FE code for a Jupyter Lab backend, but I don't think that'll affect VS debugger? I think my configs are probably just wrong. I also tried adding "debugger" to the Vue and TS code but they never got hit either.

**What I've tried:**
I've tried configuring the launch file in multiple ways
Here's my launch.json for VS debugger:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Remote debugging",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "url": "http://localhost:8888/?token=<>",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "*": "${webRoot}/*"
              }
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Webpack",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "sourceMaps": true
        },
    ]
  }
```

Here's my TS.config

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "strictFunctionTypes": false,
    "module": "amd",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "newLine": "LF",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Here's my webpack.development.js. Reason I'm posting it is cause I set source-maps under dev tools for it.

```
/**
 * Webpack configuration for production.
 *
 * Optimizes and minifies bundle.
 */

const webpack = require("webpack");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const commonConfig = require("./webpack.common.js");

module.exports = merge.multiple(commonConfig, {
  mode: "production",
  devtool: "source-map",
  main: {
    optimization: {
      minimize: true
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        minimize: true,
        debug: false
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env": {
          NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production")
        }
      }),
      // new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      //   beautify: false,
      //   compress: {
      //     warnings: false,
      //     drop_console: true
      //   },
      //   comments: false,
      //   sourceMap: true
      // }),
      new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin()
    ]
  }
});
```

Here's my webpack

```
// Entry point webpack config that delegates to different environments depending on the --env passed in.
module.exports = function(env) {
  process.env.NODE_ENV = env;
  return require(`./webpack.${env}.js`);
};
```

Here's my webpack.production

```
/**
 * Webpack configuration for production.
 *
 * Optimizes and minifies bundle.
 */

const webpack = require("webpack");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const commonConfig = require("./webpack.common.js");

module.exports = merge.multiple(commonConfig, {
  mode: "production",
  devtool: "source-map",
  main: {
    optimization: {
      minimize: true
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        minimize: true,
        debug: false
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "process.env": {
          NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production")
        }
      }),
      // new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      //   beautify: false,
      //   compress: {
      //     warnings: false,
      //     drop_console: true
      //   },
      //   comments: false,
      //   sourceMap: true
      // }),
      new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin()
    ]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to remove the `sourceMapPathOverrides` entry from your chrome launch config?

```
"sourceMapPathOverrides": {
  "*": "${webRoot}/*"
}
```

Not sure, why you set it there manually, the [default overrides](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug#sourcemaps) by VS Code should be already good, if you kept the default webpack [devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputdevtoolmodulefilenametemplate) settings (and I do not see that specified in your config). These settings affect, how webpack's custom `webpack:///` schema will be resolved for sourcemaps. Problem is, if you set something manually there, *all* defaults will be overriden.

If you can debug in `development`, but not in `production` mode, thats possibly because of a webpack/terser-webpack-plugin issue with production source maps. Watch here: [Link1](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8302), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55869571/webpack-with-sourcemap-cant-resolve-variables-in-production-mode).

E.g.

```
{
  ...
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map" (or "source-map")
}
```

does work in my environment.

Update:

I just saw, that also in your webpack development config you have `mode: "production"` set. Could you change that to `"development"` and see if it works?

Comment: Yea I did try removing sourceMapPathOverrides and devtool is set to "source-map". My suspicion is that webpack bundles it then Jupyter lab bundles it again so it loses the source mapping and therefore cannot debug.

Comment: omg..... It's works! You're a genius!! No one could figure this out, even people on the Jupyter Lab forums.

Comment: enjoy your bounty sir

Comment: note that "inline-source-map" is what allowed it to work.

Comment: glad it helped :-)